# how do i implement regular expression in amazon simpledb

Tags: amazon-simpledb

I have data stored in this format in amazon simpledb

```
source     code            success
fa.php    987439aa           true
ga.php    aa84892            false
```

how do i wrtie this type of query in simpledb

```
select * from domain_name where source = 'fa.php'
and code='ANy thing' and success = 'true'
```

How do i write code part in the above query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this select query to achieve you result -

```
**select * from domain_name where source = 'fa.php' and code is not null and success = 'true'**
```

You can not add/update/delete data using Amazon simple DB query.

Comment: Note:  "is not null" has HORRIBLE performance in SimpleDB.  Fine for small domains and/or infrequent queries, but expensive/painful to use too much...